# Exel How to run a Macro from a MERGED cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that displays a calendar when a cell is clicked. My problem is that I can't run the same macro when this cell is merged with other one. I tried makinkg the selection individual for each cell or making a range of cells. Neither of the two options worked.

My question is how to code merged cells in vba in order to run a macro. 
My code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Selection.Count = 1 Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("K12")) Is Nothing Then
            Call SHOWCALENDAR
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: When you click on where "k12" is, what is the cell name in the top left hand corner? My guess is that it's not actually k12 anymore after the merge.

Comment: @dwirony That goes off in a completely wrong direction and I don't understand how people can push the "useful" button for this. The reason the code does not run is the `Selection.count`, which is greater than 1 on a merged cell.

Answer (score 1):

`Selection.count` will return a count of all the cells in the merged cell, so it will be greater than 1 for a merged cell. Remove that count condition and the code will run fine.

Merged cells cause all kinds of headaches and should be avoided. If the cells are merged across several columns, consider using the formatting setting "center across selection" instead.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can simply try this...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Cells(1).Address(0, 0) = "K12" Then
    Call SHOWCALENDAR
End If
End Sub
```